# SQL query to match payments to invoices in Microsoft Dynamics GP (Great Plains)

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-gp

How do you match payment information from an external source to invoices in Microsoft Dynamics GP (Great Plains)?

I found this post, but it doesn't go into detail about the actual query to use:

http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/36640/189486.aspx